# --prefix to /usr/local or /opt?

Tags: linux, directory

For building apps from source like git or rails I've seen recommendations to install in both /opt or /usr/local.

From what I've read so for, the designated use for both is about the same and it amounts to merely a style issue.

Is there any practical difference? Best practices?

Answer (score 3):

The [FHS](http://proton.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) says:

> A package to be installed in /opt must
>   locate its static files in a separate
>   /opt/ or /opt/
>   directory tree, where  is a
>   name that describes the software
>   package and  is the
>   provider's LANANA registered name.

while /usr/local hold the usual /bin/, /lib, /etc, ... hierarchy

Answer (score 3):

I use `/usr/local` for stuff I put into the system, and I let third-party installers take `/opt`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to install everything I build from source in `/opt`, and edit my `$PATH` accordingly. It instils a sense of (semi-) cleanliness, and it's easier to traverse the folder structure, perform updates etc. It just comes down to personal preference; one is not necessarily better than the other (just like you said, a *style issue*).